# How to include .ts file in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3

I am making my first ionic app. I want to include an [Action sheet](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#action-sheets). I saw the [demo source](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-preview-app/tree/master/src/pages/action-sheets/basic). It has three files, `.html`, `.css` and a .ts file. How and where do we include the .ts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you just want to add a .ts file.
You can make a page using the Ionic Cli "ionic generate page pageName" and in there you can have actionSheet or whatever you want.

After running the command, ow you can see the page here:
src/pages/pageName

It will create a page where you will see another html, css and ts file
In the ts file. In the .ts file you have to import action sheet controller

```
import { ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

and in the constructor you will have to add:

```
public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController
```

and then you can use the action sheet accordingly... I can show you a demo if you want... let me know if that's helpful. Thanks

Comment: I am getting below error when I try to do it.
[ERROR] Generators are only supported in Ionic Angular projects.

Comment: I have made an open repo in which I have used actionSheets now... Please check

https://github.com/immad-hamid/ionicActionSheet

Have installed angular? using "npm install -g @angular/cli"
Can you open your terminal and run "ng -v'
let me know what it shows?

Comment: +1 Generating a component or page via the [CLI](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/) is the common way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can make a file page.ts file and you can call class of page.ts in where you want